# Creating a Image-Heavy iOS App- Online DB?- Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, backend

**Objective/ Problem**: I'm beginning to build an iOS app which will have a ton of images. It's not a photo app (it's a trivia type app) so the photos are not user photos. The app-size can't be huge as then it will take a long time to download from the App Store and take up space on the phone.

**Question**: If I'm not an expert developer or backend developer, what is my best option for storing the photos online and retrieving them as needed with simple code?

**Research:**
What I'm looking for seems to fall under the umbrella of "backend". The easy answer used to be Parse, which is a BaaS company (backend-as-a-service). However, they are shutting down. There also used to be PayPal's "StackMob", a BaaS company but they shutdown in 2014.

Both Parse and StackMob were built for people like me, indie-developers with no backend knowledge. Yet, as two of the biggest services shutdown choosing BaaS as a solution is now viewed as risky.

Big companies and expert backend developers will just build their own database, load the photos onto it, and query it as needed.

Yet, I'm no expert. Can anyone let me know what replaced Parse as being the easiest/turn-key solution? After I upload the original photos, the user will never need to add/change any.

Comment: You can try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) they are also offering the similar service. Easy to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make your file names unique you don't even really need a back end. You can just use generic web services. I handled a very similar problem using Amazon Web services S3 which just provides basic HTTP downloads.

I package groups of image file into
 zip files and then request a download of the zip to download the group of files. I found a third-party wrapper for zip decompression in Objective-C and use that  to unzip the packages into the application documents directory.

Comment: Is there a good guide for this? What makes you say that it's an easy option?I read that Amazon services are hard to setup: "BaaS's purpose is to replace your entire backend development team and infrastructure with an API driven service that front-end dev can use directly. Mobile developers represent a growing market, and typically one where you see a lot of solo developers who would be challenged to manage an Amazon instance as this requires devops skills they don't have."
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Parse-shutting-down

Comment: The S3 service is simply a place where you upload files. You can then do an HTTP GET on the files. Could not be much easier.

Comment: AWS has tons of different options. S3 is falling-off-a-log simple.